# Understanding extended perceptron

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and could understand the simple perceptron.
I came to a formula while reading about perceptron.

$$
y = \sum_{k = 1}^{K}z_{k}(x)(\Theta _{0}^{(k)} + \sum_{j = 1}^{m}\Theta _{j}^{(k)}x_{j})
$$

where 
$$
z_{k}(x) \epsilon R^{+}
$$

I could understand the inner block represents simple perceptron. and 
$$
z_{k}(x)
$$ 
is a element from real number. 
What is exactly 
$$ 
z_{k}(x)
$$ 
representing here. Could you give a hint ? 
Is it changing single layer perceptron to multi layer or other ?

Comment: where do you read this?

Comment: I would guess EITHER they mean $z_k$ instead of $z_k(x)$ OR $z_k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed function (i am assumimg you sum for $k=1,...,n$ since there is a typo in your upper sum limit)

Comment: $z^{_{k}}(x)$denotes the degree of membership for an instance x to group k

Comment: @SanjayShrestha $\sum_{k=1}^k$ is definitely a typo :-) if not by you, then by the authors of the paper. Can you link the paper? (or give the doi or whatever?)

Comment: @Max My mistake, Was a typo from my side..Changed to bigger K :)

Comment: @SanjayShrestha As Max suggested, you should link to the paper where this is written (or write in some more details), to help us understand the context.